# Why doesn't this type-check in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism

This doesn't type check:

```
module DoesntTypeCheck where {
import Prelude(Either(..));
defaultEither :: a -> Either b c -> Either a c;
defaultEither a (Left _) = Left a;
defaultEither _ b = b;
}
```

But this does:

```
module DoesTypeCheck where {
import Prelude(Either(..));
defaultEither :: a -> Either b c -> Either a c;
defaultEither a (Left _) = Left a;
defaultEither _ (Right b) = Right b;
}
```

The compiler is probably buggy, an `Either a c` type can be only `Left (x::a)` or `Right (y::c)`, if it isn't `Left` then it is `Right`, and we know that `Right :: b -> Either a b` so `Right (y::c) :: Either a c`.

Comment: "The compiler is probably buggy". First words of absolutely everybody trying to compile their first Haskell program. The real reason is never a compiler bug.

Comment: You can also write `defaultEither = first . const` with `first` coming from [`Data.Bifunctor`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html). I might, however, call it something like `setLeft`, since there's nothing particularly defaulty about `Left`.

Comment: @n.m. It's never a compiler bug for beginner programs anyway. It definitely sometimes is when you're trying to do more esoteric things.

Comment: Although compilers *have* bugs, my experience is that once you start blaming the compiler, it (close to) certainty is not. In short, a `Right x` of type `Either Int Int`, is not a `Right x` of `Either String Int`.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that when you say

```
defaultEither _ b = b
```

you're saying that the output value `b` is the same as the second input value. And that's only possible if the values have the same type. But you've told the compiler that the input has type `Either b c`, while the output has type `Either a c`. These are different types, so no wonder the compiler complains.

I understand what you are trying to do - but even though a value `Right x` (with `x` of type `c`) on its own can be of type `Either d c` for any `d`, your type signature constrains the input and output values to versions with different `d`s. And that means you can't use the same variable to refer to both values.

Comment: I don't say that the output has the same type as the second input. I only say that the output is the same as the second input. And just because they are different types doesn't mean they don't intersect! The intersection of `Either a c` and `Either b c` is precisely the values of the form `Right (y::c)`

Comment: But there is no such thing as an "intersection" of types. The value `Right (y::c)` has type `Either a c`, which you could also call `Either b c`, since the name of a type variable is arbitrary. But when you've used both `Either a c` and `Either b c` in a type signature, the compiler has to assume they're different types. It seems that you want GHC's type inference to be able to look at the implementation of `Either` and see that in your definition the `b` must be a value that could *also* be of type `Either b c`. And I don't think it's reasonable to expect it to be able to do that.

Comment: @ThePiercingPrince "And just because they are different types doesn't mean they don't intersect!"

It does mean exactly that in Haskell. Haskell's type system is nominal (as is nearly every other static type system used in programming languages) - i.e. if two types have different names they (and their values!) are fully distinct. Of course it's possible to extract the right value and inject it as another right value of a different type, but that's not going to happen automatically.

Answer (score 6):

Let's try an even simpler example:

```
data Foo x = Bar

foobar :: Foo a -> Foo b
foobar f = f
```

Take a look at the definition of `Foo`. There's a type variable on the left-hand side (`x`), which never actually appears anywhere on the right-hand side. This is an example of a so-called "phantom type variable". There's a type in the type signature which doesn't actually correspond to the type of anything in the actual value. (And this is perfectly legal, by the way.)

Now if you have the expression `Just True`, then since `True :: Bool`, then `Just True :: Maybe True`. However, the expression `Nothing` is definitely a `Maybe` *something*. But with no actual value present, there's nothing to force it to be any specific maybe-type. The type variable is phantom in this case.

We have a similar thing here; `Bar :: Foo x`, for any `x`. So *you would think* that our definition of `foobar` is legal.

And you would be *wrong*.

You cannot pass a value of `Foo a` where a value of type `Foo b` is expected, *even if* they have exactly the same run-time structure. Because the type checker doesn't *care* about the run-time structure; it only cares about *types*. As far as the type checker is concerned, `Foo Int` is different to `Foo Bool`, even though at run-time there's no observable difference.

And *that* is why your code is rejected.

In fact, you have to write

```
foobar :: Foo a -> Foo b
foobar Bar = Bar
```

to let the type checker know that the `Bar` you're outputting is a new, *different* `Bar` than the one you received as input (and hence it can have a different type).

Believe it or not, this is actually a *feature*, not a bug. You can write code that makes it so that (for example) `Foo Int` behaves differently than `Foo Char`. Even though at run-time they're both just `Bar`.

The solution, as you have discovered, is to just take your value `b` out of `Right` and then immediately put it back in again. It seems pointless and silly, but it's to explicitly signal to the type checker that the types have potentially changed. It's perhaps annoying, but it's just one of those corners of the language. It's not a bug, it's purposely designed to work this way.

Answer (score 3):

> an Either a c type can only be...

Indeed, but in your first example, the value `b` does not have type `Either a c`! As your type signature proves, it has type `Either b c`. And of course, you cannot return an `Either b c` where an `Either a c` is expected. Instead, you must destructure the value and reconstruct it with the right type.

Answer (score 0):

> an Either a c type can be only Left (x::a) or Right (y::c), if it isn't Left then it is Right, and we know that Right :: b -> Either a b so Right (y::c) :: Either a c.

I think you are confusing `type` constructors with `data` constructors. `Either` is defined like this in `ghc-base`:

```hs
data  Either a b  =  Left a | Right b
```

`Either` is a `type` constructor with two abstract variables. i.e. it takes any two types (`Int`, `String`, etc). and constructs a concrete type like `Either Int String`.

`Left` and `Right` on the other hand are `data` constructors. They take actual values like `1`, `"hi"` and construct values like `Left 1` and `Right "hi"`.

```
Prelude> :t Left
Left :: a -> Either a b
Prelude> :t Right
Right :: b -> Either a b
```

Haskell type inference **does not** work with `values` (`Left` and `Right`). It only works on `types` (`Either`). So the type checker only knows about `Either b c` and `Either a c` - so in the first case the variables don't match.