# Understand Either as a Functor

Tags: purescript

Looking into how Either is defined as a functor, I can see that

```
derive instance functorEither :: Functor (Either a)
```

which reads to me as "You can `map` an Either so long as you can `map` its element.

But either doesn't have just one element. How would this be implemented without `derive`? Here's what I've tried:

```purs
data Either a b = Left a | Right b

instance functorEither :: Functor (Either a)
  where
    map f (Right b) = Right $ f b
    map _ a = a
```

Of course, the types don't work here:

The Right has this signature: `map :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`
The Left however, isn't okay: `map :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> f a -> f a`

---

Part of my intuition is saying that `Either a b` isn't a functor, only `Either a` is a functor. Which is why `map` works over `Right` and ignores `Left`

That doesn't really give me any intuition for how this is implemented. I still need a way of matching both constructors, don't I?

On the other hand, I think an implementation of `map` that replaces the inner function with `identity` is technically law-abiding for functor? The law of composition is met if you just ignore it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While your proposed definition of the `Functor` instance indeed fails to compile, it isn't for the reason you say. And it's also "essentially" correct, just not written in a way that will satisfy the compiler.

For convenience, here's your definition again:

```
data Either a b = Left a | Right b

instance functorEither :: Functor (Either a)
  where
    map f (Right b) = Right $ f b
    map _ a = a
```

and here's the actual error that you get when trying to compile it:

```
  Could not match type

    a02

  with type

    b1


while trying to match type Either a0 a02
  with type Either a0 b1
while checking that expression a
  has type Either a0 b1
in value declaration functorEither

where a0 is a rigid type variable
        bound at (line 0, column 0 - line 0, column 0)
      b1 is a rigid type variable
        bound at (line 0, column 0 - line 0, column 0)
      a02 is a rigid type variable
        bound at (line 0, column 0 - line 0, column 0)
```

I admit that's a little hard to interpret, if you're not expecting it. But it has to do with the fact that `map` for `Either a` needs to have type `forall b c. (b -> c) -> Either a b -> Either a c`. So the `a` on the left of `map _ a = a` has type `Either a b`, while the one on the right has type `Either a c` - these are different types (in general), since `b` and `c` can be anything, so you can't use the same variable, `a`, to denote a value of each type.

([This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56016314/why-doesnt-this-type-check-in-haskell) question, although about Haskell rather than Purescript, goes deeper into explanation of exactly this error.)

To fix it, as implied in the question above, you have to explicitly mention that the value you're mapping over is a `Left` value:

```
data Either a b = Left a | Right b

instance functorEither :: Functor (Either a)
  where
    map f (Right b) = Right $ f b
    map _ (Left a) = Left a
```

which is fine because `Left a` can be interpreted on the left as of type `Either a b` and on the right as an `Either a c`.

As for what the instance "does": you are correct that "Either a b isn't a functor, only Either a is a functor" - because a functor must take one type variable, which `Either a` does but `Either a b` doesn't. And yes, because the type variable that actually "varies" between `Either a b` and `Either a c` is the one that is used in `Right`, `map` must only map over the `Right` values, and leave the `Left` ones alone - that's the only thing that will satisfy the types needed.

`Either a b` is often interpreted as representing the result of a computation, where `Left` values represent failure while `Right` ones represent success. In this sense it's a slightly "expanded" version of `Maybe` - the difference is that rather than failure being represented by a single value (`Nothing`), you get a piece of data (the `a` type in `Either a b`) which can tell you information about the error. But the `Functor` instance works identically to that for `Maybe`: it maps over any success, and leaves failures alone.

(But there's no logical reason why you *can't* "map over" the `Left` values as well. The [Bifunctor](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-bifunctors/5.0.0/docs/Data.Bifunctor) class is an extension of `Functor` which can do exactly that.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As a corollary, I take it you couldn't have `data Either a = Left a | Right a` because that extra constraint (`Left` and `Right` have the same type) means you must be able to map over both or neither.

Comment: no, you could easily write a `Functor` instance on that, which maps `f` over either `Left` and `Right` - ie `map f (Left a) = Left (f a); map f (Right a) = Right ( f a)`

Comment: As a quick follow-up, shouldn't `map _ a@(Left _) = a` work? Here the compiler should know that a was built with the Left constructor?

Comment: No, it wouldn't. Apologies, I maybe could have been more explicit - but the reason your instance doesn't work isn't to do with mentioning the `Left` constructor, it's because you're trying to use `a` as a value with 2 different types simultaneously, which can't ever work. And your version above doesn't change that. The version with `Left a` explicitly works because `Left a` has polymorphic type: `forall b. Either a b`.

Comment: I should have read your link to the Haskell thread, it's laid out very well there. Thanks for your help :) I think this really helped me understand a piece of the type system